# Permanent two-horizontal-windows configuration

Tags: window, window-splitting

I want my emacs frame to be permanently split into two (or sometimes 3 - with a different monitor - but let's talk *two* for now) columns of windows.

E.g., <kbd>C-x 0</kbd> and <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> may only affect the windows in the same "window column" as this one. Deleting a window column should be very hard (require a confirmation or a separate command).

Basically, this is functionally equivalent to having ***two frames*** side by side, except that I save on window decorations and the menu bar is re-used &c.

How do I get this without writing too much code?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to take a look at the source code of `neotree`, and then post an answer. (I want to know the answer to this question, too.)

Comment: @shynur: [`neotree`](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) appears to be similar to [sr](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar)-[`speedbar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Speedbar.html) and is thus a completely orthogonal issue: it creates a special window dedicated to the neotree buffer while I want both windows to be usable for _all_ buffers and be splittable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have been using for quite some time.
It's small and simple, but quite imperfect.

```lisp
(defun sds-split-window (size)
  "Split the window (sideways if it is wide) and switch buffer.
Pass SIZE to `split-window-right' or `split-window-below'."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (< split-width-threshold (window-width))
      (split-window-right size)
    (split-window-below size))
  (unrecord-window-buffer)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))
(define-key global-map [f2] 'sds-split-window) ; use C-x 6 for 2C-command

(defun sds-delete-other-windows ()
  "Delete other windows first vertically, then all."
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command 'sds-delete-other-windows)
      (delete-other-windows)
    (delete-other-windows-vertically)))
(define-key ctl-x-map "1" 'sds-delete-other-windows)

(defun sds-swap-buf ()
  "Change the buffer to `other-buffer'."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))
(define-key global-map [f8] 'sds-swap-buf) ; same as C-x b RET
```

I would love to see something more robust (even at an expense of large code base - as long as it is maintained by someone else ;-).